# List with arrays to sub class

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api

I have a JSON string with a list of arrays. I would like to set the array to a different class.

Here's my JSON:

```
{ "timestamp" : "1390257561" ,
  "bids"      : [ [ "833.98" , "3.14189766" ] ,
                  [ "833.73" , "0.08396004" ] ,
                  [ "833.65" , "9.64222506" ]
                ] ,
  "asks"      : [ [ "834.48" , "0.38622500" ] ,
                  [ "834.60" , "5.47589215" ] ,
                  [ "834.61" , "1.36021122" ]
                ]
}
```

Here's my class:

```
public class OrderBook
{
  public double TimeStamp { get; set; }
  public List<PriceAmount> Bids { get; set; }
  public List<PriceAmount> Asks { get; set; }
}

public class PriceAmount
{
  public decimal Usd { get; set; }
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The object in the list can't be filled because the object PriceAmount is an array. To let this code work the object (Array) should have a name in front of them. For example:

```
{ "bids" : [ [ "Usd":"833.98" , "Amount":"3.14189766" ] ,
             [ "Usd":"833.73" , "Amount":"0.08396004" ]
           ]
}
```

How can I read the list array into a sub class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this. First, a simple data structure to hold the parsed data, with a simple factory method to instantiate it:

```
internal class ParsedJson
{
  public uint                Timestamp { get; set; }
  public List<List<decimal>> Bids      { get; set; }
  public List<List<decimal>> Asks      { get; set; }
  public static ParsedJson CreateInstance( string json )
  {
    ParsedJson instance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParsedJson>( json );
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Then use that to bootstrap something that more approaches a usable business object:

```
internal class MyData
{
  public static MyData CreateInstance( string json )
  {
    DateTime   unixEpoch = new DateTime( 1970 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
    ParsedJson record    = ParsedJson.CreateInstance( json );
    MyData     instance = new MyData
                          {
                            TimeStamp = unixEpoch.AddSeconds( (double)record.Timestamp ) ,
                            Bids      = record.Bids.Select( x => new BidAsk( x[0] , x[1] ) ).ToArray() ,
                            Asks      = record.Bids.Select( x => new BidAsk( x[0] , x[1] ) ).ToArray() ,
                          } ;
    return instance;
  }

  public DateTime TimeStamp { get; private set; }
  public BidAsk[] Bids      { get; private set; }
  public BidAsk[] Asks      { get; private set; }

  private MyData()
  {
    return;
  }

  public class BidAsk
  {
    public decimal Price  { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public BidAsk( decimal price , decimal amount )
    {
      this.Price = price;
      this.Amount = amount;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have that, usage is simple:

```
class Program
{
  private static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    string json = @"
{ ""timestamp"" : ""1390257561"" ,
  ""bids""      : [ [ ""833.98"" , ""3.14189766"" ] ,
                    [ ""833.73"" , ""0.08396004"" ] ,
                    [ ""833.65"" , ""9.64222506"" ] ,
                  ] ,
  ""asks""      : [ [ ""834.48"" , ""0.38622500"" ] ,
                    [ ""834.60"" , ""5.47589215"" ] ,
                    [ ""834.61"" , ""1.36021122"" ] ,
                  ] ,
}
";
    MyData data = MyData.CreateInstance( json );
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could deserialize it to

```
public class OrderBook
{
    public double TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public List<List<decimal>> Bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<decimal>> Asks { get; set; }
}
```

and then transform `List<List<decimal>>` to proper `PriceAmount` objects.

Comment: How can i transform it to the right object? I really have no idea.

Comment: @Freddy: The point is to separate your serialization classes from your business classes. Have a `SerializableOrderBook` which uses `decimal` values, and a separate `OrderBook` which has `PriceAmount` values. Then create a simple `OrderBookConverter` which you can write code which converts to/from the serializable types.